# Shopify - creating a free trial product that becomes a subscription?

Tags: shopify

I want to be able to offer a product for free on the first month, and afterwards turn into a subscription.

Is there any way to add a dynamic clause to charge $0 on the first month + $3 shipping and afterwards routinely charge $19.95 and have free shipping without creating 2 products?

Comment: Shopify does not have a built in subscription service. You'll have to look at plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Shopify can offer such kind of "deep" customizations within their [Shopify PLUS](https://www.shopify.com/plus/?ref=microapps) plan.

Comment: Is there an alternative without having to rely on that? That's really for more bigger stores ( starts at $1000/mo ).

Comment: I'm currently using the ReCharge plugin which handles subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this would be to use an Offsite payment gateway which accepts dynamic payments and multiple configurations such as installments or recurring billing. You can yourself [build](https://docs.shopify.com/hosted-payment-sdk/getting-started) your own conector between Shopify and an existing payment gateway (there should be tens of gateways with great APIs around) which should be pretty easy and fast.